# How to pull year and month from every month between date range into list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have start and end dates 2017-11-23 and 2018-03-13 respectively.

My output would be a list of 2D lists:

```
[[2017,11],
[2017,12],
[2018,1],
[2018,2],
[2018,3]]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You should show us what you've tried.  To get you started, take a look at the `datetime` library, specifically the `datetime` and `timedelta` classes.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/
Try reading up on Python's time handling facilities, especially the `datetime` package.  With a `timedelta` of one day, you should have no trouble writing the list comprehension to provide your desired output.

Comment: I think I have some reading to do on timedate and timedelta. I've had a read of the official Python documentation, but it's mostly jibberish to me... I'm relatively new to Python and have learnt by examples only really.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `datetime.date`, especially if you already use it for other aspects of your program's date handling.

```
import datetime

def generate_months(start, end):
    start = start.replace(day=1)
    end = end.replace(day=1)
    while start <= end:
        yield [start.year, start.month]
        try:
            start = start.replace(month=start.month+1)
        except ValueError:
            start = start.replace(year=start.year+1, month=1)


start = datetime.date(2017, 11, 23)
end = datetime.date(2018, 3, 13)

result = list(generate_months(datetime.date(2017, 11, 23),
                              datetime.date(2018, 3, 13)))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple class with a `__sub__` method:

```
s = ['2017-11-23', '2018-03-13']
import functools
class Date: 
  def __init__(self, _d):
    self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['year', 'month', 'day'], map(int, _d.split('-'))))
  def __sub__(self, new_date):
     _y, _m = self.year, self.month
     _result = [[_y, _m]]
     while _y < new_date.year or _m < new_date.month:
       _m += 1
       if _m > 12:
         _y += 1
         _m = 1
       _result.append([_y, _m])
     return _result

final_result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y:x-y, map(Date, s))
```

Output:

```
[[2017, 11], [2017, 12], [2018, 1], [2018, 2], [2018, 3]]
```

Note, however, you can also use the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date(*map(int, s[0].split('-')))
d1 = datetime.date(*map(int, s[-1].split('-')))
result = {(d + datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y-%m') for i in range((d1-d).days+1)}
final_result = sorted(map(lambda x:list(map(int, x.split('-'))), result))
```

Output:

```
[[2017, 11], [2017, 12], [2018, 1], [2018, 2], [2018, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `dateutil` by doing `pip install python-dateutil`
After that you can use `dateutil.rrule` to iterate over date/time between two timestamps

```
>>> from dateutil import rrule, parser
>>> d1=parser.parse('2017-11-23')
>>> d2=parser.parse('2018-03-13')
>>> 
>>> f = lambda d: [d.year, d.month]
>>> [f(d) for d in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=d1, until=d2)] + [f(d2)]
[[2017, 11], [2017, 12], [2018, 1], [2018, 2], [2018, 3]]
>>>
```